# New event system android

Tags: unity-game-engine

I had such a problem, I reinstalled Windows and completely forgot about the file for Google play keystone.  So, I created a new project and moved the Assets folder to it (except Google play), all external saves were saved, but a new error appeared, the new event system stopped working, I use FirstPersonController, everything works in Unity and simulation device editor, but as soon as the build on Android Clicks the user interface, they don't they work ( maybe someone has free time and can go to anydesk and help?)

if you create an empty scene and do not use the old ready-made scene from the old project, and just create a canvas there, throw the add event system button on it, everything works, but as soon as you add a new input system and prefab player event system does not work in build in android

Comment: did you change the eventsystem to the new input? ()and its not a new event system)

Comment: Can you change the keystore in old project?

Comment: @kennarddh I have already created a new project and a new page in google play, and was also able to create a new key and build google play, but when I launch on android, the interface does not react at all(

Comment: do you use the new input system package?

Comment: @BugFinder no, I didn't change anything, I just copied the assets folder without Google play, and if I copy it with it, it will ask for the binding of the key file, but I don't have it because I changed Windows and forgot about this file (the build runs and works in Unity without errors, the problem arises in build android when the test on the phone UI does not reacts

Comment: And now you lose the keystore and cannot publish update to play store?

Comment: @kennarddh yes yes, the only option I know to publish the application is to create a new project and generate a new binding key ( I did so, but now the event system does not work, but only when the game itself is tested on the android, in unity device simulator everything works well but the ui does not react in any way on android

Comment: do you still have the old full project? If you build the old project to apk and install to your phone does it works?

Comment: @kennarddh yes i have old full project, but unity does not allow you to build it, it requests a key file ((

Comment: Change the keystore?

Comment: @kennarddh how can this be done ?

Comment: Wait i forget how im gonna try it first.

Comment: @kennarddh build FAILED (((

Comment: @kennarddh see my error build sdk ?gradle and java

Comment: Hmm I don't know about that error. Try to reinstall the android sdk?

Comment: @kennarddh  default api 12 level was<3 ty i upgrade API for 34 level and project build now <33

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the keystore in the old project and create new google play store app

Open the android publishing setting *Ignore the warning*
[image]

Then press `Keystore Manager...` button

Create a new keystore or just use if you already have other keystore that you know what is the password

[image]

I'm gonna create new keystore and press `Add Key`
[image]

Then the new keystore will be used *Ignore the warning*
[image]

To be sure you can select the new keystore *Ignore the warning*
[image]

Now you need to enter your password select the alias then enter the alias password.

Now you can publish your old project as new application in google play store.

Comment: thank you very much,created a new keystore, I clicked the build project button, waiting now